# Why is hash function in hashmap and hashtable declared as final?

Tags: java, hashmap, hashtable

Looking through hashmap code, the hash function used to compute the hash to avoid / reduce collision is final. A final prevents overriding but why should it prevent overriding if someone wants to ?

```
 final int hash(Object k) {
```

Comment: Remember what the keyword `final` means when placed on a method?

Comment: final prevents function from being overridden, but why should it behave that way ?

Comment: Someone didn't want that function being overridden.  Why?  That's really something that you should ask whomever wrote those classes.

Comment: Where did you find this method ? I don't see it in the code!

Comment: Its not a part of jdk 7. its in one of the previous versions.

Comment: Which version of Java is it present in?